# Составить регулярку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть такой вот html код, пытаюсь выдрать +13

```
<span id="c_votes_24649">
  <a href="#" onclick="App.c_votes(24649, 'plus'); return false;">+</a>/<a href="#" onclick="App.c_votes(24649, 'minus'); return false;">−</a>
  (+13)
</span>
```

сделал вот такое Г (:

```
preg_match("#<span id=\"c_votes_.+?\">.+?</a>.+?</a>(.*?)</span>#s",$content,$out_raiting);
```

только вот именно из скобок выдрать не выходит, пробывал экранировать эти скобки типа такого

```
preg_match("#<span id=\"c_votes_.+?\">.+?</a>.+?</a>\((.*?)\)</span>#s",$content,$out_raiting);
```

выдает пустой массив, непойму почему

Comment: т.е. вы были на правильном пути, вся соль только в пробелах/переносх строк и т.п. символах.А вообще лучше перед поиском прогонять исходный текст и заменять все спецсимволы (пробелы, переносы строк, табуляции) на ''. Тогда такая проблема отпадает

Comment: Поищите генератор регулярок.

Answer (score 3):

Может конечно извращенно переделал вашу без того извращенную регулярку, но она работает ))

```
#<span id=\"c_votes_.+?\">.+?</a>.+?</a>[\s\(]*(.*?)[\s\)]*</span>#s
```

по крайней мере в данном примере.

А вот так будет покороче, но надо проверять, а то мало ли какие нюансы могут в тексте быть:

```
#(?<=</a>)[\s\(]+(.*?)[\s\)]*</span>#s
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, если только из этого текста надо выдрать, то самое простое написать

```
preg_match('/\((+\d{1,})\)/s', $content, $out_raiting)
```

т.к. "+" и далее 2 цифры уникальны, а вот если там достаточно большая страница, то надо смотреть и возможно будет проще через парсер DOM  добраться до этого "+13", т.к. скорее всего у тэга "`<span>`" уникальный для страницы id, а "+13" - это text в dom дереве.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*\((\+\d+)[^<]*</span>$
```

или так, +число в круглых скобках перед последним закрывающим тегом `span`